# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My complete code is here http://pastebin.com/xwJ2zi2y. I am trying to do, when the value of Ajax refresh_token function value change it should call the order_list function. when I refresh the page, it gives the output of order_list function once but when It start interval the refresh_token it gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefine" on line 94 in pastebin code. And did not run order_list function, when the value of refresh_token changes. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

shouldComponentUpdate help me to resolve this issue. see the below code before render function.

shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {                                                          return true;
                 },

my complete running code is here http://pastebin.com/xwJ2zi2y.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the context for the usage in the success callback. Here your fixed function:

```
refresh_token : function(){
                    var self = this;
                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: "/order/refresh",
                      headers: {
                       Accept : "application/json",
                       "Content-Type": "application/json"
                      },

                      success: function (resp){
                                 var newToken = resp;
                                     console.log(newToken); //it give the value of refresh eg. ["20150925313"]

                                 if(newToken != self.state.token){

                                   self.setState({ token: newToken});
                                            //      console.log(this.state.resp);
                                 } 
                              }
                    });
                },
```

Comment: Thank you very much MysterX, this resolve this error. But still I am not able to call the Orderlist component when token value changes.

Comment: Hi MysterX, thank you very much for this help, could you help me to find out why my code not calling orderlist function when token value changes.

Comment: @Amit, sorry, but I dont use react and didnt study it, so I cant give you more help